# Sabnzbd+binary newsgrabber: service not enabled, ubuntu

Tags: 14.10

```
SABnzbd+ binary newsgrabber: service not enabled, edit /etc/default/sabnzbdpl
```

This message shows up in my terminal. I googled it, but no answer to be found. I am a Ubuntu newbie.I guess I missed a step, maybe something with init. Who can help? ;)

I installed SABnzbd, then made sure it is updated automatically: like this:

```
gksu add-apt-repository ppa:lottanzb/ppa
The program 'gksu' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksu add-apt-repository ppa:lottanzb/ppa
The program 'gksu' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gksu
sudo apt-get install gksu
[sudo] password for ninti: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libssl0.9.8 libufe-xidgetter0 webaccounts-extension-common
  xul-ext-websites-integration
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgksu2-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gksu libgksu2-0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 99,6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 740 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libgksu2-0 amd64 2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4 [71,8 kB]
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe gksu amd64 2.0.2-6ubuntu2 [27,8 kB]
Fetched 99,6 kB in 0s (844 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libgksu2-0.
(Reading database ... 203906 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgksu2-0_2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgksu2-0 (2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gksu.
Preparing to unpack .../gksu_2.0.2-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gksu (2.0.2-6ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libgksu2-0 (2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/libgksu/debian/gconf-defaults.libgksu-sudo to provide /usr/share/gconf/defaults/10_libgksu (libgksu-gconf-defaults) in auto mode
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up gksu (2.0.2-6ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
ninti@ninti-K52Jc:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus start
[sudo] password for ninti: 
 * SABnzbd+ binary newsgrabber: service not enabled, edit /etc/default/sabnzbdplus
```

Comment: I could guess as to what goes wrong, but the official installation procedure for SABnzbd is much easier. Simply find the package in the Software Center and click install.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I did install it from the Software Center, yet it didn't work... I have to edit this file: /etc/default/sabnzbdplus, but the outcome is: 
bash: /etc/default/sabnzbdplus: Permission denied

Comment: Try `sudo nano /etc/default/sabnzbdplus`.

Comment: Hi Jos, I did that, just now, once more. But than what to do? I've copied and pasted the outcome above in my original post..

Comment: At this point, `sudo /etc/init.d/sabnzbdplus restart` should work.

Comment: this is the outcome, again.... SABnzbd+ binary newsgrabber: service not enabled, edit /etc/default/sabnzbdpl

Answer (score 1):

Sabnzb can only run as a service after we had filled in the required fields in its configuration file `/etc/default/sabnzbdplus`.

```
# [required] user or uid of account to run the program as:
USER=<your_username>
```

Give in your `<your_username>` in the above line. To edit a file in `/etc` we need root permission, e.g. by running either one of both commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/sabnzbdplus
gksu /etc/defaults/sabnzbdplus
```

**Note:** Editing files as root may have unwanted side-effects on system stability. We should only do so if we know what we are doing.

But, we do not need to run sabnzb as a service every time the computer starts. It is perfectly fine to only run it when we need it by clicking on its icon from the Dash, or by running

```
sabnzbdplus --browser 1
```

in a terminal (this will open the web-interface in your browser in a default setup, say `0` to not open in a browser).

Comment: required] user or uid of account to run the program as:
USER=<s.marges4@upcmail.nl>

# [optional] full path to the configuration file of your choice;
#            otherwise, the default location (in $USER's home
#            directory) is used:
CONFIG=

# [optional] hostname/ip and port number to listen on:
HOST=
PORT=

# [optional] extra command line options, if any:
EXTRAOPTS=

Comment: How to enter this? If I press Enter, it skips a line, when I want to close the terminal, it says a program is still running.

Comment: I removed sabnzbd and installed it again. I manually have to upload the nzb to sabnzbd and than it works. It will do for now.... thanks for your help!